# Contact form 7 redirect after sending to tab where the form is

Tags: wordpress

Good Morning

I have a problem with contact form 7, I have the contact page with 3 horizontal tabs, and on each tab, I have a different form, the problem is that when I send the form the second or third tab it sends normally, but returns For the first tab that is the first form, and what I sent is in another tab, so it does not show the confirmation message for the user, then to see the message I have to click on the tab in which I filled out the form ..

Is there any way to redirect the form of the second or third tab, once it is sent, back to the same tab in which the submitted form is so that it already displays the user confirmation message?

Comment: Does your url change according to the selected tab. Something like yoururl.com/#tab2 ?

Comment: Yes, it adds the form id submitted
Ex: # wpcf7-f534-p15-o2

Comment: More even changing the url .. contact / # wpcf7-f534-p15-o2
It returns to the first tab, this form being the second tab .. (where is the form submitted with the confirmation message to the user)

Comment: When you submit the form of the second tab, it changes the url with the id of the submitted form, but still returns to the first tab where the first form is, and not to the second tab that is submitted form.
LINK: http://solez.com.br/novo/contato/